# Get raw data from Http Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save the raw, full data of an `HttpRequest`. At the moment I have this:

```
Request.ContentEncoding.GetString(Request.BinaryRead(int.MaxValue));
```

But this only gets the body of the HttpRequest. I also want to get the headers. In the raw form, http requests are transfered as header fields followed by the body, so it should be possible to get the raw text representation of the whole request, but I can't work out how.

Comment: To get the TCP/IP headers in raw form you need to use a Socket or TCPSocket

Comment: @craig1231 Thanks for the tip, but I was refering to Http headers rather than TCP/IP headers. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull them out of the [`Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers.aspx) property (Apologies for this being kind of an obvious suggestion). It may not be as convenient as "give me everything in raw format", but it's code you will only have to write once.

Comment: I guess I'll have to do that then. I want to log the plain text request, so I didn't want to try to recreate it from headers + body unless necessary.